# How to add Validation constraints dynamically in parsley js

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

Hi I'm validating few fields in form and using `parsley.js` for that, There are few situations where I have to add validation constraints dynamically using JS but Parsley is not accepting it. Please Have a look at code and correct me :

JS(All of what I have tried):

```
$('#billForm').parsley().destroy();

$('#customerAccount').parsley('addConstraint', {'length' : '[10,10]' }); //This is one way I tried

$('#customerAccount').attr({'length' : '[10,10]' }); //This is another way I tried

$('#billForm').parsley();
```

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: if possible a jsFiddle ?

Comment: It is not dat big thing, There should be a method call or property that I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the correct attribute (which is `data-parsley-length` if you're using Parsley 2.x).:

```
$('#billForm').parsley().destroy();

$('#customerAccount').attr('data-parsley-length', '[10, 10]');

$('#billForm').parsley();
```